# PhoneGap Android plugins won't load

Tags: android, cordova

I've been trying to install and use the ChildBrowser plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser for PhoneGap and the FaceBook plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser. With both these I've run in to the same issue, the Javascript call to invoke plugin methods won't work. The debug output shows:

TypeError: Result of expression 'window.plugins' [undefined] is not an object.

Is there something I might be missing to enable plugins in PhoneGap?

Comment: Are you loading phonegap.js in your html?  It creates the windows.plugin object

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the Javascript file in your index.html?
Check that the Javascript file has this -

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("childBrowser", new ChildBrowser());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/697 says :

"The addPlugin/addConstructor methods were dropped in 2.0.0. Take a look at the ChildBrowser, TTS or VideoPlayer plugin to see how to modify the js code."